# Installation error oracle-java8-installer

Tags: lubuntu, java

I tried installing java on ubuntu 16.04, but getting the following error

```
Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback': Not a directory
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I removed the installation with the following commands

```
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

but still the error is same, hope somebody can help me, thank you.

Comment: The answer below and a complement: What you did to try to solve it is a waste a time. Keep it in mind for the next occurrence. Purging this particular installer does nothing because although not a meta-package in a strict sense, it acts like one. apt clean doesn't do what you think it does and removing a PPA to later add the same gets you to the exact same point as before.

Answer (score 3):

You need to manually remove the package post install scripts:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java8-installer.postinst -f
sudo dpkg --configure oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have run the steps you mentioned, and run the following command. sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer, so the out put is oracle-java8-installer is already the newest version (8u151-1~webupd8~0), but java -version gives the output The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
It means, java is not installed on system, so how I can install it.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall oracle-java8-installer`

Comment: This is the final part of the output, Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback': Not a directory
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having trouble installing java8 I would suggest manually checking any other files for java- and then reinstall them.

```
sudo ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/  
# check for extra java.list files and remove
# as stated above - be sure your pervious install postinst is rm
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java8-installer.postinst -f
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
# test it to be dpkg is happy
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

It will then tell you that java9 is now the stable default. If you specifically need java8 (wazuh on an elk stack for example) then you must specify the default version of java for the system to use.

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Let us know if it you resolved it and how please?